# How to promote the package with UniversalPackages@0 task in AzureDevops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Is there an option to promote universal package view with azure devops yaml task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to promote universal package view in `UniversalPackages @0` task. As a workaround, besides using extension, you can also promote universal package view through script in powershell task.

```
$token = "Enter your Pat here"

$url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_apis/packaging/feeds/FeedID/upack/packagesbatch?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  "data": {
    "viewId": "Release"
  },
  "operation": 0,
  "packages": [{
    "id": "YourPackageName",
    "version": "PackageVersion",
    "protocolType": "upack"
  }]
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

Enter your own PAT in `$token`, and replace the `OrgName`, `ProjectName`, `FeedID`, `YourPackageName`, `PackageVersion` with your own ones, you can set `PreRelease/Release` in viewID to promote universal packages in Azure DevOps feed view from `@local` to `@pre-release` to `@release`.

Test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this extension:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.vsts-promotepackage-task

It allows you to promote packages in a feed.